# Looping through mysql json data

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

Working with Laravel 5.3 and MySql 5.7 using `json` column type. I am not able to loop through the saved Json in my view. Here is how my setup looks:

Saved JSON in `"Merchants"` column:

```
["stores", "website"]
```

Retrieving this JSON with Eloquent:

```
   $navigation = Merchant::select('merchants')
   ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
   ->get();

   return View::make('dashboard', compact('navigation'));
```

Lastly my **View:**

```
  @foreach($navigation as $key => $value)
      <li><a href="#">{{$value->merchants}}</a></li>
  @endforeach
```

The results don't loop through the saved `JSON` instead it just displays the actual JSON saved, eg: `["stores", "website"]` however I want to loop this so it would list each value from the json array, eg:

```
<li>stores</li>
<li>website</li>
```

Thanks.

See my attached dump:

[image: dump]

Comment: Did you try to dump the Value to See what type it has? I really think that it'll be a string and you need some kind of accessor function in your Model to turn it into the Array you want

Comment: hey @FabianBettag see attached.

Comment: Yep, that's a string. You'd need to cast it to a PHP equivalent. See @phaberest s answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [cast it](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) in the model.

```php
protected $casts = [
    'merchants' => 'json'
];
```

#### EDIT

You may need to change in your blade

```
@foreach($navigation as $value)
  @foreach($value->merchants as $merchant)
    <li><a href="#">{{$merchant}}</a></li>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: She casting but getting htmlspecialchars()  error. Any ideas?

Comment: You now have an array, but you can't print it in the `<a>` tag as it is not a string. Loop through the `merchants`.

Comment: Thankyou! So for future reference, when saving json to mysql JSON columns, I should always cast it? What about dealing with multiple dimension arrays?

Comment: Yep, exact. You can just use a `text` column instead of `JSON` datatype and anyway cast it as json. As it is fairly new, I still prefer text over json. The result is the nearly the same.

Comment: Thanks for your time and knowledge! Will pass it on! x